# Using the midpoint rule

Tags: approximation, linear-approximation, approximate-integration

QUestion: [image]

needed help here.
i had tried it out but i get an answer that is not in the question answer list.
i get 0.846474251 and i just assumed 0.63689453.

see my workings below i used a tabular method of finding midpoint approx.

[image]

Comment: Hint: the exact value of the integral is $2/\pi=0.636619772\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\Delta x=\frac{1}{6}$ and taking the function value at interval midpoints you get
$$\int_0^1\sin\pi xdx\approx\sum_{n=0}^5\Delta x\cdot\sin\left(\pi\left( \frac{\Delta x}{2}+\frac{n}{6}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{1}{6}\cdot\sin\left( \pi\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{n}{6}\right)\right)$$$$=\frac{1}{6}\cdot(0.258819+0.707107+0.965926+0.965926+0.707107+0.258819)$$$$\approx0.643951$$